# Derech Eretz with animals?

Tags: halacha, animals, derech-eretz-manners

Is it permitted to eat in front of animals? Eating in front of fellow human beings when they don't have food [is considered a breach of Derech Eretz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adECZemJ2o4) as it might make them hungry, or repulse them, or make them sick. If one must do so, one is obligated to very strongly offer them to partake of the food.

This wouldn't work with animals. Especially dogs. One can feed dogs before one eats<sup>1</sup>, and then if a person would - after they have eaten - eat in front of them, the dogs would still desire the food just as much. It's almost impossible to eat in front of the dog without causing the dog a lot of distress and hunger pangs. Anyone who has ever had a dog would know! It is actually *assur* to give one's animals human food that is still good<sup>2</sup>, so one can't feed them. Even if one can find a solution to that<sup>3</sup>, one would still not be solving the problem. They will continue to want more and more and no amount of offers of food would satisfy them.

So I am just wondering if there is any discussion about whether it is allowed to eat in front of (well fed) dogs? Is there any translation of the laws of Derech Eretz for animals?

---

<sup>1. As is halacha. See Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 42:1

2. Taanit 20b, cited in Magen Avraham 171:1

3. See Machatzit Hashekel OC 171:1</sup>

Comment: Would one argue that this law of D'E would be even stronger when applied to animals, because at least with humans you can talk to them, explain the situation etc.? Animals, just like small children, are stuck with their umwelt

Comment: They are like humans. Even if they are full they still want to eat because they like eating. Not that they have hunger pangs.

Comment: I don't know if this qualifies as an answer but there is some degree of derech eretz. The Midrash Tehillim 37:1 relates that Avraham asks Malkitzedek (AKA Shem) with what did you merit to come out of the Ark, and he responds that they practised charity - namely they did not sleep as they were serving one animal after another all night long.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tehillim.37.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%A2%D6%B5%D7%A6%D6%B8%D7%94%20%D7%94%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%A1%D6%BB%D7%92%D6%BC%D6%B6%D7%9C%D6%B6%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%AA%D6%B5%D7%A8%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%A9%D6%BC%D7%82%D6%B8%D7%93%D6%B6%D7%94